# How do I add an article to specific page?

Tags: posts, pages, shortcode

Regardless of it being WooCommerce or WordPress, I want to add a couple articles to specific pages, so they show there instead of the images that are there now.
[Homepage](http://www.wein-partner.at/wp/home/)
I know, I'm supposed to use shortcodes for that, but for some reason I can't get it to work.
For example:
This one has post ID 1305, so you'd imagine I use

```
[display-posts id="1305"]
```

to show it on that page, but it only displays the shortcode itself.
I thought displaying posts by shortcode was one of WP's basic functions, wasn't it?
Do I have to code a custom shortcode just for this to work?

Any advice?

Comment: since it wouldn't work for some reason, I ended up using a plugin for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to put PHP code in the editor you need a plugin, same goes for display-posts.

Display Posts shortcode isn't a built in function. https://wordpress.org/plugins/display-posts-shortcode/

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[display-posts id="1305"]'); ?>
```

Comment: nothing. Now (since I removed the image to show only the article) it displays nothing.
For your information, I added it in the backend - edit page.
Afaik it should take PHP code as well.
I suppose I could try adding it to the page-template.